# DocuSign Terms of Service modal pop up code giving Cross site scripting error and failed to display

Tags: docusignapi

Here is my sample code to open the Terms of Service pop up using the docusign API. I've taken it from the official docusign api documentation.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
     <script src="https://assets.manywho.com/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://demo.docusign.net/clickapi/sdk/latest/docusign-click.js"></script>
 
        
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script> 
            $(document).ready(function()
            { 
    docuSignClick.Clickwrap.render({
     environment: 'https://demo.docusign.net',
     accountId: 'c5731c88-7330-443e-9a76-f56d99c0f4c6',
     clickwrapId: 'f53a4fdd-e8b6-4a07-b87a-e305f19df720',
     clientUserId: 'UNIQUE_USER_ID'
    }, '#ds-terms-of-service');

            }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
       <div id="ds-terms-of-service"></div>

        
    </body>
</html>
```

```
enter code here
```

Unfortunately, It isn't working. It is giving the cross site scripting error in browser console.
[image]

Kindly help out with this issue.

Comment: I do not see Cross scripting error in the logs, it is some invalid src error. Did you create a clickwrap in your DS Account via WebApp? Also `c5731c88-7330-443e-9a76-f56d99c0f4c6` your accountId and `f53a4fdd-e8b6-4a07-b87a-e305f19df720` your clickwrapId? Also in `clientUserId` you need to set a unique value for the user who will load the page like that user's emailId or employeeId etc try by setting `1234567`.

Comment: Thanks @Amit K Bist 
The solution by adding 6 digit number as Unique id works for shared code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify some unique identifier for clientUserId. It could be an email address or something. That would be used to record the consent and if you try to use the same one again - it won't show again.
You can add some random number if that's what you need. See how our [latest sample app - MyClickwrap](https://sampleapps.docusign.com/myclickwrap/) does it. You can get the open-source code of [GitHub](https://github.com/docusign/sample-app-myclickwrap-csharp).